# Mac Yosemite, PHP activate openssl extension

Tags: php, macos, yii2

I have installed PHP 5.5.14.

I'm starting to use Yii2, the whole installation process using "composer" working properly.

The problem arises when I access "http://localhost/basic/web/" to validate the installation and project creation.

At this point an error:

**PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_openssl.dll' - dlopen (/ usr / lib / php / extensions / no-debug-non- zts-20121212 / php_openssl.dll, 9): image not found**

I'm trying to figure out how to properly activate this librearia.

I enabled the extension in the php.ini file, but no luck.

Do not know how to fix it :(

Thank You!

Comment: you're on a mac, trying to load a .dll, which is a Windows library... so... yeah.. totally wrong configuration on two fronts: the file doesn't exist, and even if it did, it'd be for the wrong operating system anyways.

Comment: dll ?? you're on mac os. Are you sure you have uncommented / added the good library source in php.ini ?

Comment: Yes, I know, I think I got the bug in shaping the "php.ini" apache .. that is used by Yii2, is it true? @MarcB

Comment: OK i solved de problem.. .. i restarted the MacBook, and the problem has been fixed.

No happened ... but ... is resolved.

Thank you guys for your help!